# Select an IP address in a regex group from a multi line string

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to select an IP address from a routing table and am not having much luck crafting a sed or grep expression.

I have the below regex that is valid and selects group 1 as expected in regex testers.

```
.*0\.0\.0\.0\/0.*(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b).*eth0.*
```

I've been able to easily get the output I need via awk, however the bash variable is null when the script is executed in my environment.
I've tried various expressions with sed and awk, but there seems to be more selectors required than I'm familiar with

```
/usr/bin/vtysh -c 'show ip route' |
sed -n 's/.*\(\b\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}\.\d{1,3}\b\).*eth0.*/\1/p'
```

The input is below

```
Codes: K - kernel route, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP,
       O - OSPF, I - IS-IS, B - BGP, E - EIGRP, N - NHRP,
       T - Table, v - VNC, V - VNC-Direct, A - Babel, D - SHARP,
       F - PBR, f - OpenFabric,
       > - selected route, * - FIB route, q - queued route, r - rejected route

S>* 0.0.0.0/0 [210/0] via 9.16.24.1, eth0, 1d06h57m
S>  0.0.0.0/0 [300/0] via 9.16.26.1, eth1, 1d06h57m
O>* 10.0.0.0/19 [110/42] via 10.255.255.21, eth1, 1d06h56m
  *                      via 10.255.255.22, eth1, 1d06h56m
```

expected output:

```
9.16.24.1
```

Comment: Related: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) - in particular, `\d` is a PCRE feature and you are missing escapes required for BRE on the final quantifier `{1,3}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a job for `grep` (GNU) or `awk`, rather than `sed`:

```
grep -Po "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}(?=, eth0)" file
```

Ouput:

```
9.16.24.1
```

Comment: This got me on the right track. I also found how to reset the selector when lookahead is not fixed length with \K: `/usr/bin/vtysh -c 'show ip route' | grep -Po "^.*0\.0\.0\.0\/0.*via \K[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}(?=, eth0)"` which filters for the specific default gateway I'm looking for.